# how to change fluid to object

Tags: fluid-simulation, transform-orientation

new to the forum, my name is carl.
I would like to create an animation of a fluid that at the end of the race turns into a fruit. Could you please tell me what technique to use to achieve this result.
I've already created my fluid which explodes on contact with a solid, I've also created the fruit but how do I merge them. thanks for your answers .see you later

Comment: What do you mean by "at the end of the race turns into a fruit"? Can you please give more details?

Comment: Hello, I've created an animation of a fluid splashing on a bottle of fruit juice, and when it splashes I'd like the drops of water to turn into fruit ...